# Simple definition of Bondi Radius

Tags: radius

Can anyone help me by defining what is exactly Bondi Radius? I have searched far and wide but the results are very complicated and so far I have only rough idea of it but I just cant explain it very well

Comment: You mean you can't find the formula $r_{\rm B} = GM/(v^2+c_s^2)$ or you are having a hard time interpreting it?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape probably "so far I have only rough idea of it but I just cant explain it very well" makes it pretty clear

Comment: @uhoh As per usual, it would be better if you would not speak for other people, but let OP voice their opinion instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the mysterious site *[Vaporia](http://astro.vaporia.com/start/bondiradius.html)*, which is a fantastic index for astrophysics terms (and other things I'm seeing now):

> The Bondi radius is analogous to the [Hill radius](http://astro.vaporia.com/start/hillradius.html), both giving an idea
>   of how far from an object, a medium (gas, dust) is likely to be drawn
>   in and accreted. The Bondi radius takes into account the (relative)
>   speed of the object through the medium, and the medium's density and
>   sound-speed. Accretion due to material falling within the Bondi radius
>   is called Bondi accretion.

Try to picture a heavy object, perhaps a planet, travelling through a gaseous or dusty medium. Now, some of the gas is eventually going to be the victim of accretion to the planet. The planet is going to pull gas/dust from the medium and the Bondi radius tells you how far from the planet gas/dust is likely to be accreted to the planet.

Hopefully this is more clear!